# c# : Arranging child controls at certain position in a flow layout pannel

Tags: c#, combobox, flowlayout, flowlayoutpanel

my first post and quite new in c# programming. googled and searched lot of forums but could not find the answer to my specific question.

I'm implimenting a GUI which reads some values from a USB device. Once the button (read_usb_button) is pressed,  the app read the values from the USB device and displayes them in 4 different combo boxes as  shown  below.

```
                     Read_USB_button
```

switch_combox      switch_combo2      switch_combo3   switch_combo4

```
                      exit_button
```

Now after selecing the values from "switch_combo1", "switch_combo2" and ...."switch_combo5"  , the GUI should look  like this.

```
                     Read_USB_button
```

switch_combo1      switch_combo2     switch_combo3    switch_combo4
port_combo1                       port_combo1                      port_combo1          port_combo1
port_combo2         port_combo2        port_combo3     port_combo2
port_combo3         port_combo3        port_combo3     port_combo3

```
                      exit_button
```

but I'm always getting the results as shown below, (comboboxes keeps on adding below the first row)

```
                        Read_USB_button
```

switch_combo1         switch_combo2        switch_combo3     switch_combo4

port_combo1
port_combo2
port_combo3
port_combo1
                                                                               port_combo2
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         port_combo3
.
.
..
...

```
                            exit_button
```

I want to add the combo boxes  paralleley as soon as  the user select any of the "switch_combon" combo boxes. so that they keep on adding till the GUI is filled.

I've tried flowbreak() method of the flowlayout pannel but unable to get the proper solution.

I've tried differnet combinations of set bound method  but it also did not work.

any help will be highly appreciated.

BR,

Rana